# How can I open a nodejs Duplex stream given a file descriptor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, polling, libuv

I'm porting an existing program to nodejs. In this program, I open a file descriptor and then hand it off to a thread which calls `poll` on it in order to determine when it's readable.

Instead of writing a custom C++ module, I'd really like to do this in pure javascript making use of Node's handy dandy [Duplex stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex).

For example I'd like to do something like this:

```
var device = new PollDuplexStream(fileDescriptor);

device.on('data', function(data) {
    // data handling logic here
});

...

var chunk = new Buffer(...);
device.write(chunk);
```

It seems like this should exist, but I'm not seeing where it does. Perhaps I'm just blind? What's the real world equivalent of `PollDuplexStream` from the example above?

Please note that I'm explicitly looking for a solution which starts with a file descriptor rather than a path, otherwise I'd just create my own from `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream`.

Also I don't care that it calls `poll` internally - in fact, I'd prefer that it use libuv's `uv_poll_*` internally.

Comment: `var stream = new net.Socket({ fd : fd })`

Comment: Would it matter that the fd isn't for a socket?

Comment: should work for sockets and pipes

Comment: Yeah, but my fd is neither. It's a character device.

Comment: then try `tty.ReadStream` and `tty.WriteStream`. Related discussion: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7101

Comment: `createReadStream` also takes a file descriptor as an argument, have you tried that?

Comment: @loganfsmyth does createWriteSteam as well? Can you point me to the docs which shows that w/ an answer rather than a comment? If it works I'll happily accept

Comment: @vkurchatkin same to you - if you write up your answer as an answer rather than a comment, I can at least upvote it. Thought I'm not convinced this is the best solution, as what I'm reading is neither a tty, nor a socket.

Comment: @BenBurns You can see it in the example options in the docs: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options `fd`. It isn't in the docs, but `createWriteStream` also supports it.

Comment: See https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7707 for fs.createReadStream notes/discussion and https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7708 for fs.createWriteStream regarding the `fd` option.

Comment: Why is everybody commenting instead of posting answers?

Comment: @natevw - search the text on the page of issue 7707 for "benjamincburns" ;-)

Comment: @natevw - nevermind, I see you responded to me... :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a binary addon which uses a uv_poll_t handle, which is able to poll for readability / writability for arbitrary file descriptors.